# change current active state of bottom tab on a list item click in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Data data = mListDatas.get(i);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ThirdFragment thirdFragment = new ThirdFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putSerializable("detail", data);
            thirdFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.replace(R.id.content,ThirdFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();


   BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView)view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_bottomview);
            navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_third_tab);


        }
    });
```

In the above code i need to open a new fragment on the bottom tab from a list item click,

i am able to open a new fragment but the current tab remains unchanged i.e, after redirecting to the third fragment on third bottom tab ,the current tab i.e, Second Tab is active.

How can i change the active state of bottom tab from second tab to third tab on the list item click ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity needs to implement the `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`. This can be done simply by adding `implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` after your class name, this is done so you can get the click callback whenever one of the bottom menu items are clicked on.

Then you need to override the `onNavigationItemSelected` function so add the following code to your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.tab_1:
            handleFragmentChange(Fragment_1.newInstance());
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also add `navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);` in the same activity once you have found the view using findViewById. This is done so that the system knows that your class is handling the event when a bottom menu is clicked so it calls the above function in your class.

The return true is what notifies the android system that it needs to switch the tab.

Comment: can u just elaborate

Comment: @MIDHUNCEASAR i have added a few more details to the answer, let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: Actually what i need to achieve is that to open the third fragment which is placed in third tab PROGRAMMATICALLY(not on usual click)...i am currently in first fragment,and able to open the third fragment but the  first bottom tab is in the active selected state....i need to change the active selected state to third bottom tab

Comment: What i want is something like below, but i want to perform it in FRAGMENT not in an Activity i have already performed handling the click of bottom tabs the way u suggessted

    `BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id);`

   `View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.menu_action_item);
view.performClick();`

Comment: So you have a say 3 tabs, from fragment 1 you want to open fragment 3 with the respective tab highlighted correctly so in this case tab 1 would be highlighted and then tab 3 would be, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes exactly .....i am able to open the third fragment programmatically without tab click....but even if i open the third fragment the first bottom tab is in the active state

Comment: You need to create a callback to your activity that hosts the bottom navigation and change the tab there, you can follow this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity if you have any trouble doing it please create a question and link it back here, I'd be happy to answer it but lets not hijack the current users question any further.

Comment: es i have resolved the issue by creating a method in activity that has View view = navigation.findViewById(R.id.navigation_thirdMenuItem); view.performClick(); and call this method in the fragment

Answer (score 0):

if this code locates in fragment then you need to replace

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_bottomview);
navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_third_tab);
```

before

```
...commit();
```

and add getRootView() because your BottomNavigationView locate inside main container - root activity

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.navigation_bottomview);
navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_third_tab);
```